# erro mysql com chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, sql

estou criando uma modelagem porém estou esbarrando em um erro quando vou criar as cHaves estrangeira o MYSQL da um erro "Cannot add foreign key constraint". segue meu sql.

```
use fatec;


create table aluno(
 ra int not null primary key,
 nome varchar(255),
 cidade varchar(255),
 endereco varchar(255)
);


create table diciplinas(
 id int not null  primary key auto_increment,
 nome varchar(255),
 carga_hor int
);


create table professores (
 id int not null primary key  auto_increment,
 nome varchar(255),
 cidade varchar(255),
 endereco varchar(255)

);



create table turmas(
 id int not null,
 id_diciplina int not null, 
 id_prof int not null,
 ano int,
 horario varchar(5),
 primary key(id)
 CONSTRAINT FK_diciplinas foreign key(id_diciplina) references diciplinas(id),
 CONSTRAINT FK_professor foreign key(id_prof) references professor (id)

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probleminha com os nomes das tabelas né. Sei que é confuso. Ter a tabela `aluno`, e a tabela `professores` cria uma confusão tremenda no singular e no plural.

Uma dica: põe tudo no plural: `professores`, `turmas` e `alunos`, ou tudo põe tudo no singular.

Troca:

```
create table turmas(
    id int not null,
    id_diciplina int not null, 
    id_prof int not null,
    ano int,
    horario varchar(5),
    primary key(id)
    CONSTRAINT FK_diciplinas foreign key(id_diciplina) references diciplinas(id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_professor foreign key(id_prof) references professor (id)
);
```

Por:

```
create table turmas(
    id int not null primary key,
    ano int,
    id_diciplina int not null,
    id_prof int not null,
    id int not null,
    horario varchar(5),
    foreign key(id_diciplina) references diciplinas(id),
    foreign key(id_prof) references professores(id) 
);
```